# Distribute strings into minimum amount of lines

Tags: uniform-distribution

I am a software developer and I have a set of strings that I want to distribute into a minimum amount of lines using programming code. Each line has a known maximum length and I know the length of each string.

So I suppose the math question I have is: I have a collection of numbers that I want to distribute into collections with a known maximum sum and use a minimum amount of those collections.

Lets assume I have a max line length of 50 and I have these string lengths:
14,50,28,22,22,25,20,15

A solution could be (in random order):
14,20,15 (sum = 49)
50 (sum = 50)
28,22 (sum = 50)
22,25 (sum = 47)

Is there a mathematical formula or technique that can solve this puzzle?

I tried to search for similar questions, but I guess I don't know what keywords to search on. Also as a non-mathematician, its hard to tag this question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is called [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) and it is NP-Hard.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.I went for sorting the strings on size and filling the lines one by one while always taking the largest possible string that fits in the remaining space.